# Python SSL verification fails

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I am trying to setup a Python TCP client-server session, but the client side is throwing this error: `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)`

I am using a freshly generated LetsEncrypt certificate. I've stored the fullchain.pem (public certificate) on my computer which I'm running the client from, and yet it can't verify the authenticity. I am sure that `fullchain.pem` is the public key and `privkey.pem` is the private key, so I don't see why this isn't working. I've also tried using `cert.pem` for public too, which does not work either. Is anyone able to provide some insight on as to why the verification fails? Below is the client and server programs.

Client:

```
import sys
import socket
import os
import ssl
from backports.ssl_match_hostname import match_hostname, CertificateError


def connect(hostname, port, message):
    """
    Connects to the hostname on the specified port and sends a message

    :param hostname:
    :param port:
    :param message:
    :return:
    """

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # create a TCP socket
    try:
        s.connect((hostname, port))  # establish a TCP connection to the host
        #ca_certs_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'fullchain.pem')
        ctx = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
        #sslsock = ctx.wrap_socket(s, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, ca_certs=ca_certs_path)
        sslsock = ctx.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname='encryptio.tk')

        # Check if the server really matches the hostname to which we are trying to connect
        match_hostname(sslsock.getpeercert(), hostname)

        sslsock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))  # send the message
    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit('[-]' + str(e))


def main():
    connect('encryptio.tk', 12000, 'Client says hello')  # replace '' with the hostname, 12000 as the port, and 'Hello' as the message


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Server:

```
import sys
import socket
import ssl
from backports.ssl_match_hostname import match_hostname, CertificateError

# Servers do not care whether clients connect with certificates

def listen(port):
    """
    Listens on the specified port and accepts incoming connections

    :param port:
    :return:
    """

    # server_socket - welcoming socket
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(('', port))  # establish welcoming socket

    ca_certs_path = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/encryptio.tk/fullchain.pem'
    priv_certs_path = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/encryptio.tk/privkey.pem'

    # listen for TCP connection requests.
    server_socket.listen(1)  # parameter specifies the maximum number of queued connections (at least 1)

    ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    ctx.load_cert_chain(certfile=ca_certs_path, keyfile=priv_certs_path)

    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    print('[*] The server is ready to receive')

    while 1:
        try:
            # When a client knocks on this door, the program invokes the accept() method for
            # server_socket, which creates a new socket in the server, called connec-
            # tion_ocket, dedicated to this particular client. The client and server then complete
            # the handshaking, creating a TCP connection between the client’s client_socket
            # and the server’s connection_socket
            #connection_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()

            #sslsock = ssl.wrap_socket(server_socket, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, server_side=True, certfile=ca_certs_path, keyfile=priv_certs_path)
            connection_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
            sslsock = ctx.wrap_socket(connection_socket, server_side=True)
            data = sslsock.read()
            #message = connection_socket.recv(1500)

            print('[+] From' + str(addr) + ': ' + 
data.decode('utf-8'))
        except Exception as e:
            sys.exit('[-] ' +  str(e))

        #connection_socket.close()
        sslsock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        sslsock.close()


def main():
    listen(12000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

EDIT:
I tried setting the CA in the client side program to a root certificate, and now I get this error:

```
[X509] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3053)
```

Comment: shouldn't ssl_version should be defined for both client and server?

Comment: @Matt.Stroh Probably. I tried doing that and I also added the argument cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED to the server program, yet I still have the same issue.

Comment: The server needs to provide all certificates up the the built in root. This means your certifile needs to contain not only the server certificate but also the chain certificate leading to the root. In case of Let's Encrypt you have your server certificate signed by `Let's Encrypt Authority X3` but you add the ca certificate for this CA too since the trusted root CA is the issuer of `Let's Encrypt Authority X3`, i.e. `DST Root CA X3`.  See https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich So in the server's fullchain.pem I would add a root CA such as https://letsencrypt.org/certs/lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.pem.txt to the file?

Comment: @Chase: You need to add the chain ((also called intermediate) certificate(s) not the root certificate. Validation of the certificates includes building the trust path to the locally trusted root CA and therefore the client needs to get the server certificates and all intermediate certificates up to (but not including) the root CA from the server. They also need to be provided in the correct order with server certificate being the first.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm just noticing right now as I compare that the Let's Encrypt Authority X3 is already inside of the fullchain.pem after the server's certificate. Given that, I think it should work but it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your client you have this:

```
 ca_certs_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'fullchain.pem')
     sslsock = ssl.wrap_socket(s, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23, 
 cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, ca_certs=ca_certs_path)
```

The default for `ca_certs` is None in `ssl.wrap_socket` which means that you have to provide a useful path if you use the non-default `ssl.CERT_REQUIRED`. Only, the path you provide seems to be the certificate chain you use in your server, i.e. server certificate and chain certificates but not the root certificate. Instead the `ca_certs` on the client side should only contain the root certificates, since this is the trust anchor which is used to build the trust chain using the certificates sent by the server (i.e. server certificate and chain).

Instead of using your own CA store you might also use the system wide store. With current versions of Python you can simply use the following code which creates a SSL context using the default CA store and with certificate and hostname validation enabled and then upgrades the socket to SSL and checks the certificate properly:

```
 s.connect((hostname, port))
 ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
 sslsock = ctx.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname='example.com')
```

Comment: Using the code above I get these errors. Client: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:777). Server:  [SSL: PEER_DID_NOT_RETURN_A_CERTIFICATE] peer did not return a certificate (_ssl.c:645). I can't put anymore keywords in wrap_socket like CERT_REQUIRED or PROTOCOL either.

Comment: @Chase: I have no idea what's wrong  but it looks like a problem with your server. Though it worked for me without problems with the code you've given. Maybe the certificate you have setup for the server is wrong - hard to tell without knowing what exactly you have in your certificate and key file.

Comment: I tweaked the server code using what I read from the ssl documentation, and now the SSL connection works. I've edited my question to reflect the changes. Namely, I used create_default_context on the server too and then used load_cert_chain for the certificates.